# How to verify that node_modules is in sync with package-lock.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

In a script, I want to verify that the contents of `node_modules/` correspond to what is defined in `package-lock.json` or whether an (expensive) `npm ci` is needed.

I think I might be able to run `npm install --dry-run` and parse the following line:

```
added 670 packages, removed 390 packages, updated 421 packages and audited 101551 packages in 16.337s
```

But that seems brittle.

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: `npm ls` determines if `npm ci` is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To only show the diff (if any) of `node_modules` contents against `package-lock.json`:

```
npm list 2> /dev/null | grep 'invalid: "'
```

`2> /dev/null` mutes the errors of `npm list` and then greps the slightly-more-readable standard output as a finite list of discrepancies.

I prefer to grep the standard ouput because the error output does not report the `package-lock.json` version and I find it a valuable reference to have at a glance.

---

Edit: It is still safer to list the errors, since a missing dependency fits the grep "missing", not "invalid"

```
npm list 2>&1 | grep -E '^npm ERR! \w+: '
```

Comment: Oh, nice find! `npm ls` has also a `--json`  option that should be easy enough to use!
Now I just need to remember what I needed that for, 3 years ago 

Docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ls